# D3.js V4 migration issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Just like many of you I'm having some difficulties converting my legacy code to D3.js v4. Now I'm running into an issue for which I cannot find documentation and don't find how to fix it.

This was my original code :
https://jsfiddle.net/pt11q8hL/

and I managed to convert it to: https://jsfiddle.net/m6vzt2sp/

But now I'm stuck since

```
d3.stack().offset('wiggle').values(function(d)
```

Returns an error that

```
d3.stack(...).offset(...).values is not a function
```

Help figuring out what the correct syntax should be would be appreciated, also if you see any other things that need to be converted let me know.

Comment: There is a bunch of stuff wrong with your code, your best bet would be to comment everything out and debug line by line to fix it. Refer to the [API Reference](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md)  to know what to call. Hint: `values is not a function`. In general, you can't convert v3->v4 code, rather, you need to rewrite it in the new version as too many things have changed. my 2c.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Andrew in the comment, I would suggest the following general steps based on my experience migrating some scripts to v4,
first strip off the axis, scaling and animation code,
make sure the main modeling code functions or debug it,
once you get it working start adding in the scaling, making sure it functions as expected, 
then add the axis, and from there you can move to all the animation-if any-
again doing it from scratch following the documentation is your best bet, as the changes between v3 and v4 are mostly paradigm (logic) changes not syntax.